# Identify which Platform Events have been queued successfully and which one unsuccessfully

Tags: apex, platform-event

I am working with **High Volume** and **Publish After Commit** Platform Events and I am trying to understand if there is a way to know which Platform Events have been queued successfully.

We invoke the `EventBus.publish(events)` method providing the list of Platform Events we want to publish and we receive a `List<Database.SaveResult>`.

Since we are working with **High Volume** Platform Events, we know that the `Database.SaveResult` object gives us only the information regarding the successful or unsuccessful queuing operation for a specific Platform Event: it means even we receive a successful SaveResult, the related Platform Event may not be published later on.

My initial goal was to implement a tracking process for all the Platform Events:

1. I create a list of Platform Events I want to publish;
2. I invoke the `Eventbus.publish()` method providing the list of Platform Events;
3. The `Eventbus.publish()` method returns a list of `Database.SaveResult` objects. Each `Database.SaveResult` object contains a reference (or the values itself) to a Platform Event and it gives information regarding the queuing operation (successfully/unsuccessfully).

Comment: You're conflating queueing and publishing. As the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_considerations.htm#pe_async_publish_errors) explains, publishing of the event by the queue is async.  Queueing the event via EventBus is reflected in `SaveResult`.  EventBus with high-volume platform events is at-most once delivery. If you need [at-least once delivery or exactly-once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44204973/difference-between-exactly-once-and-at-least-once-guarantees), then choose technology that supports this.

Comment: @identigral I am not confusing queuing and publishing. I have clearly mentioned that point. As I said, since I am working with High Volume Platform Events, when I invoke the Eventus.publish() method, the Database.SaveResults returned are giving info about the queuing (and not the publishing). And it is exactly what I would know: which Platform Events have been queued successfully/unsuccessfully.

Comment: Fair enough - our comment still stands. You're expecting something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Looking at the comments, looks like you are clear on what you want to ask. But the question is a bit misleading (at least to me). I guess you want to find whether a PE event was actually published to and received by the subscriber or not. Anyways, take a look at the answer I have posted.

Comment: there appears to be a pilot for getting callbacks on published events status - https://twitter.com/RajSFDC/status/1504144908302503942

Comment: With AWS as the consumer, SF rolled up this whole problem into a solution (AWS Event Relays): https://medium.com/salesforce-architects/accelerating-salesforce-and-aws-integration-with-event-relays-c92673f5f3e5

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce hasn't exposed a `REST` endpoint or a `EventBus` method to get the information you are looking for (*primarily, this might be because HVPE are persisted and published asynchronously as mentioned in [High-Volume Platform Event Persistence](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_considerations.htm#pe_async_publish_errors)*). However, you could achieve this via a custom solution making use of `EventUuid` mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_event_uuid.htm). Fetch the `EventUuid` while publishing and compare it against the one obtained at subscriber.

1. Since, you are using `EventBus.publish` method, you can call `EventBus.getOperationId(saveResult)` for every `Database.SaveResult` object returned by the publish method and store the `EventUuid`s in another custom object.
2. The platform event can be listened by multiple subscribers, which can then carry out different actions. So, you can add another subscriber to the event via apex trigger (*the  actual subscriber in your case may be an external one*), fetch the `EventUuid` and compare it against the ones stored in custom object.

**Note:**

1. I don't think this method was provided in the platform to run for bulk of platform events as proposed in this solution, but rather for checking few platform events. Regardless, the proposed solution should work.
2. Also, I tried `getOperationId` method calls within a FOR loop with 10000 `SaveResult` objects in a single apex transaction and didn't come across any governor limit violation.

Comment: Thanks arut for your help. 
Maybe I was not clear enough in my initial request.
Your solution is a step ahead of what I am looking for.
Basically, your solution helps identify which Platform Events are published (asynchronously) successfully and which ones are not. It means those PEs had been already queued successfully!
So, using the UUID we are able to understand if a queued PE is published or not.

My investigation is working one step before your solution.
I would know if it is possible to know which PEs are queued successfully and which ones are not.

Comment: @vt89 `List<Database.SaveResult>` returned by `EventBus.publish(events)` give you exactly that info. In `SaveResult` object, success flag indicates that PE has been queued and error flag indicates that it wasn't queued. AFAIK, the queueing would occur immediately, but the publishing is asynchronous.

Comment: @arut  The docs are misleading. Getting (an/some) Event UUID from `EventBus.getOperationId` does not imply successful publish by the queue to the subscriber. There's no reliable (transactional) way to know the result of a publish. At best, you can be notified of an error: see [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.220.0.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_publish_notification_channel.htm). See this [related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63826451/mulesoft-with-salesforce-streaming-api-using-cdc) for more fun with messaging.

Comment: @identigral Looks like SF needs to update their documentation. Looking into [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.220.0.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_publish_notification_channel.htm) & [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_event_uuid.htm), its seems like `operationId` & `EventUuid` are essentially the same.

Comment: @identigral I do agree that getting `EventUuid` from `EventBus.getOperationId` does not imply successful publish, but comparing them against the corresponding IDs received at subscriber end will help determine which HVPEs were not published. Async publish errors notification (beta) feature is good (I hadn't noticed it); it simplifies the solution. You should post it as another answer, since it seems to be the only available easier option now. However, I do agree that there is no reliable way for the publish tracking (its documented officially in the developer guide).

Comment: @arut Yup, we're on the same page.